# convert hatanaka to rinex for multiple files

Tags: terminal, gps, converters, command-prompt

I need to convert hatanaka files (.d) to rinex (.o) for multiplle files (about 3000 files) is there  fast way or script that I can use in terminal (ubuntu) or command prompt (windows)?

thank you

i hope i can convert my hatanaka files to rinex for multiple files

Comment: You can use the CRX2RNX utility, which is specifically designed for this task.